# How is the authentication token generated for the IBM Tivoli Netcool/OMNIbus ObjectServer REST API?

Tags: authentication, authorization, tivoli

We have an application that sends a request to an IBM Tivoli Netcool/OMNIbus 8.1 server's ObjectServer REST API. It sends a GET request to `http://1.2.3.4/objectserver/restapi/alerts/status?filter=Severity=5%20and%20Manager%20not%20like%20'^.*Watch$'` with the following HTTP headers:

```
Authorization: Basic DHCteF92S53fhUY6jlF=
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Type: application/json
```

The request works fine in our dev environment, and the REST API returns the requested alert information. However, in our test environment, the REST API returns a "401 - Authorization Required" error.

The `DHCteF92S53fhUY6jlF=` value in the Authorization header seems to be some sort of authentication token, and it is hardcoded in our application. The developer who wrote that code is long gone, and I have no idea how that value is generated. Maybe it is incorrect for our test environment and thus the 401 error. How is that authentication token generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything can create the Basic authentication header. It is the base 64 encoded value of the `username:password` phrase.

In your test environment, base64 encode the current `username:password` for the account you want to use, and add it to the header.

You can use a site such as the following if you need a tool:

https://base64decode.org/

https://www.debugbear.com/basic-auth-header-generator